# Can't ping a Windows 10 machine from my Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, windows-8.1

I'm trying to ping a Windows 10 machine from a Windows 8 machine but it doesn't work unless the Windows 10 machine pings the Windows 8.

I've tried many tutorial and disable the firewall but the problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

Try disable firewall **both** on the windows 10 and windows 8, if there is any other devices between the two PC such as router make sure that the route between windows 10 and windows 8 is allowed.

Or, enable the icmp-in/icmp-out both on the two PCs.

[image]

If above steps does not help. Try reset the TCP/IP by cmd.exe.

```
netsh int ip reset
netsh winsock reset
```

Comment: It doesn't work